# Delete virtual serial ports in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port

In my registry file `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` there are 14 ports that I want to delete – `\Device\VCom11` to `\Device\VCom24`.

I deleted the ports with Registry Editor but after reboot they come back. I don't know what app creates them.

Comment: Do you have any programs that use COM ports?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [auto generated registry key](http://xpregistry.uw.hu/xpr0043.html). Hmm. Some registry keys are dynamically created by Windows on BOOT. Things like no. of processors etc are detected on boot and then Windows creates specific registry keys for ease of use for Kernel components and other Windows applications. These registry keys will be re-created after every reboot.

Comment: Thank you for the help The driver that create VCom is XPVCOM I disable In the computer Management.I deleted the ports with Registry Editor,thanks.